# Returning gtm.elementId as category in Google Analytics from Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm currently using Google Tag Manager to track when users of a site open a dropdown. I'm using the "Element Visibility" trigger which fires when the class of the dropdowns can be seen on screen. The Tag fires correctly when the dropdown appears on screen:

[image]

and from the Data Layer I can see that gtm.elementId is the expected ID:

[image]

My question is how do I then take the gtm.elementId and show it as an Event Category in Analytics when the tag is fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not obvious, but you can catch this with built-in variable:

> gtm.elementId - the ID value of the element that became visible. You
>   can capture this with the Click / Form ID Built-in Variable.

as noted by Simo Ahava (https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/element-visibility-trigger-google-tag-manager/)